# Update statement gives error with some IDs and not others

Tags: triggers, insert-update

Have a database that I restored from a backup on a new sandbox server. I ran a very innocuous update statement:

```
UPDATE insurance 
    SET  plan_text='MS MEDICAID'
WHERE insurance_id=168331
```

I received the following error:

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure insurance_track_rev_type1, Line
>   70 [Batch Start Line 0] Cannot find either column "master" or the
>   user-defined function or aggregate "master.dbo.GetHashGuid", or the
>   name is ambiguous.

I changed the ID, the new statement is as follows:

```
UPDATE insurance 
    SET  plan_text='MS MEDICAID'
WHERE insurance_id=168334
```

I received the following:
(1 row affected)

I have no idea what is going on. Any ideas?

JG

Comment: Sounds like SQL Server. Is it? Do you have a trigger on insurance table?

Comment: That was it. A trigger referencing a dll that was not present. Thank you.